# How to check what form data are posted?

Tags: php, curl

I want to post some data (leaving comment on a post) to an asp.net website using PHP cURL.
But it always failed.

Not sure if I missed any form data.

So I want to know what kind of tools/software can check what form data are posted to a web page? I guess I may have missed some fields.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use firebug on Firefox or Chrome Developer Tools for Google Chrome for this type of operation.

For Chrome :

1. Right click on an element in the page and select "Inspect Element"
2. Got to the Network panel
3. Submit your form
4. The first line should be the call to the server to submit your data. Click on it to analyze the headers and detect which parameters have been posted to the server

Example for StackOverflow : open the developers tools, go to network, then enter a search in the box on the upper right and you see the first line being "search" with a method GET. Click on it and you see the parameter `q` with the value you searched

Edit : A lot of form come with a hidden input field with a unique code generated on the server that must be provided when submitting, I guess you are missing this info when submitting with curl. You can check the form element in the developer tool to see if there is a hidden field or not too.

Comment: Thank you sooo much @koopajah !! You solved my problem!
The website actually contains a submit button which is image type and I missed out the parameters of submit.x, submit.y

Thank you again! :)